# CreateTableOne output not showing categorical variables

Tags: r

I am trying to create a Table 1 of descriptive statistics of both continuous and categorical/binary variables in R using the tableone package and CreateTableOne command. I am getting a Table 1 with only the continuous variables showing up. Below is the code I used to first convert numeric variables to categorical and then try to create my Table 1. Maybe the problem is in how I am converting the variables from numeric to categorical? Many thanks in advance for any suggestions!

#Convert numeric variables to categorical variables

names <- c("smoking", "alcohol", "livewithpartner", "maternal_yrs_schooling", "maternalage", "hshldincome", "srq20binary", "wave")

finaldata[,names] <- lapply(finaldata[,names], factor)

str(finaldata)

#Get variable names

dput(names(finaldata))

#Vector of variables to summarize

myVars <- c("people_hshold", "totalchildren_under6", "totalchildren_6andover", "srq20sum")

catVars <- c("smoking", "alcohol", "livewithpartner", "maternal_yrs_schooling", "maternalage", "hshldincome", "srq20binary")

#Create Table One

tab1 <- CreateTableOne(vars = myVars, strata = "wave", data = finaldata, factorVars = catVars)

print(tab1, showAllLevels = TRUE)

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems here:

1. The input data is missing in the question so no one other than yourself can run the code in the question.  Also library statement(s) are missing.  Please read the information at the top of the [r](/questions/tagged/r) tag page about posting and note questions must have self contained complete reproducible code and inputs that anyone can easily run by copying it from the question and pasting it into their R session.
2. All the variables wanted along the left side of the table should be listed in the vars argument.  In the question only the continuous ones are listed so those are the only ones output.
3. There is no need to convert the categorical variables to factors (although it does not hurt).  Just listing them in the factorVars arguments should be sufficient.  If they are already factor, character or logical they don't have to be listed in the factorVars argument (although it does not hurt).  The only purpose of the factorVars argument is to make those columns which are numerically coded but should be regarded as factor to be regarded as such.

For example, using the built in anscombe data frame suppose we want to use x1, x4, y1 and y2 where x1 is to be regarded as categorical even though it is not a factor in anscombe, x4 is the grouping variable and y1 and y2 are continuous.  Then we use the following. Note that x1 is listed both in vars and in factorVars.

```
library(tableone)

tab1 <- CreateTableOne(vars = c("x1", "y1", "y2"), strata = "x4", 
  data = anscombe, factorVars = "x1")
print(tab1, showAllLevels = TRUE)
```

giving:

```
                Stratified by x4
                 level 8            19            p      test
  n                      10            1                     
  x1 (%)         4        0 ( 0.0)     1 (100.0)   0.358     
                 5        1 (10.0)     0 (  0.0)             
                 6        1 (10.0)     0 (  0.0)             
                 7        1 (10.0)     0 (  0.0)             
                 8        1 (10.0)     0 (  0.0)             
                 9        1 (10.0)     0 (  0.0)             
                 10       1 (10.0)     0 (  0.0)             
                 11       1 (10.0)     0 (  0.0)             
                 12       1 (10.0)     0 (  0.0)             
                 13       1 (10.0)     0 (  0.0)             
                 14       1 (10.0)     0 (  0.0)             
  y1 (mean (SD))       7.82 (1.82)  4.26 (NA)      NA        
  y2 (mean (SD))       7.94 (1.49)  3.10 (NA)      NA
```